# Socket not closing when calling socket.close()

Tags: java, sockets

I found the same problem in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303628/socket-not-closing-serverside-when-calling-socket-close-in-client-java), but i think it wasn't solved.

i'm going to be brief, this is my code:

```
try {
Socket pacConx = new Socket(ip, Integer.parseInt(port));
DataInputStream  dataIn = new DataInputStream(pacConx.getInputStream());
DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(pacConx.getOutputStream());

while(){...}
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.fatal("error", e);
}finally{
    if (dataIn != null) {
           dataIn.close();
     }
     if (dataOut != null) {
            dataOut.close();
     }
      if (pacConx != null) {
            pacConx.close();
      }
}
```

First, i connect to the server using the code above, and it succeed.
But, when i try to REconnect to the same server and port after a while, i cannot reconnect. 
Apparently the first socket is still "alive" in the serverSide.

is the a solution to my peoblem ?

Is there a way that i can close the other "alive" socket ?

Comment: Are you sure that the while loop ends ?

Comment: What's listening on the server side? Do you have access to the code?

Comment: Yes, i have access to the code. I'm listening to  a server that's going to serve me with stock data.

Comment: yes, the while loop ends. and even if it doesn't end and i force it to end, this doesn't close the other socket.

Comment: What problem? What exception? What error message? Be specific.

Comment: There's no exception. But i can't REconnect to the server. When i called the administrator, he told me that he sees one opened conection with the server (meaning that the first socket didn't close well).

Comment: There's no exception but you can't reconnect? What happens instead? And does this server really only handle one connection at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
...
dataOut.flush();
dataOut.close();
...
```

Paste error message or/and full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate an orderly disconnect. After calling flush on the streams, and before calling close on the socket, add this:

```
pacConx.shutdownInput();
pacConx.shutdownOutput();
```

That tells the remote end you're finished and allows it to dismantle the port without waiting to make sure there isn't data still in transit.

Answer (score 0):

For about 2-4 minutes after you close the socket it will hang in "CLOSE_WAIT" state on the server.  This is a normal part of the TCP/IP protocol to handle delayed packets still wandering around in the network.

This should be handled by your server code.  Is it unbinding its listen socket while handling a request and trying to re-establish it after the close?  If so, it should either leave the listen up during processing or re-establish it with a SO_REUSEADDR option.

Comment: i don't have the server code, nor the server in front of me (it's in another town). So how can i make things work fine ? (because i don't see any code :s )